# Dropdownlist Default item c# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, entity, dropdown

I have 4 dropdownlist in my c# code i am filling them from a list which is filled from my database. I want to 4 different default value for each dropdownlists but if these default values are in my list every dropdownlist show these 4 values at the same time but if my list doesn't include default values

```
drpdwnlist1.SelectedValue = "Default1..";
```

this code give error because list doesn't include these default value (Default1)

What should i do for different default values for each dropdownlist while the other dropdownlists not having others default values ?

Comment: Don't set the `SelectedValue` if you do not know the value. Or use `SelectedIndex`

Comment: How is your dropdown list being populated?